# editing the array I've included instead of editing the file of included array php

Tags: php, object-oriented, array

In order to reduce time complexity, instead of loading (and then dumping to use it for later) the whole file into an array (It would be O(n) with n=number of lines), I have saved it as array into a PHP file and included it

**index.php**

```php
<?php
include "english.php";
$test = new English("false_friend.php");
?>
```

**english.php**

```php
<?php
class English {
private $dict;
private $lib;
private $size;
private $f;
public function __construct($lib) {
    include $lib; //instead of reading the whole text file I save it into an array which is saved in a PHP FILE
    $this->lib = $lib;
    $this->dict = $dict;
    $this->size = filesize($lib);
    $this->f = fopen($this->lib, "r+"); //it's a pointer in order to modify my "phisical" library for later
}
public function search($key) {} //future function
public function delete($key) {} //future function
public function insert($key, ...$values) {
    if (!isset($this->dict[$key])) {
        fseek($this->f, $this->size - 4);
        $array = '" => [';
        foreach ($values as $value) { $array = $array.'"'.$value.'",'; }
        $array = substr_replace($array, "],", -1);
        fwrite($this->f, '  "'.$key.$array.PHP_EOL.');?>');
        $this->size = filesize($this->lib);
        $this->dict[$key] = [...$values];
    }
}
}?>
```

**false_friend.php**

```php
<?php
$dict = array(
    "eventually" => ["alla fine","possibly"],
    "commodity" => ["merce","comfort"],
);?>
```

In this way, since I use a pointer, insertion's time complexity is O(1) //I edit the last 4 bytes by adding the new content, I dont affect previous ones

search'complexity is O(1) as well, but a "delete() function" could have in worst case time complexity of O(n). If I had milions of lines, it would not be a great deal.
**My goal is editing the array I've included instead of editing the file of included array**, maybe implementing array as MinHeap which insertion, search and deletion have time complexity of O(logn)

Comment: Splatpacking is not more efficient versus `array_values()`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57725811/2943403 ...do you need to?

Comment: Any concerns regarding simultaneous file read/writing? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46016784/2943403 Am I reading your script correct that you are maintaining a persistent connection to file (`fopen()`) while other processes will determine what needs to happen to the file?

Comment: @mickmackusa the problem is: if I had to remove the first key, I would be forced to edit the whole file (=> O(n) ) since I don't know how to permamently edit the array I included. My goal is: taken (or included) an array, edit it without edit the file

Comment: @mickmackusa add this snippet in index.php `$test->insert("hello","dog"); print_r($test);` Refresh index.php and you'll notice you added `hello dog`  in false_friend dict. But I didn't work on the array, I worked on the file. I'm trying to avoid it

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!